# Django redirect to a page on click

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

you'll probably know that I'm a newbie in django from my question.

I want to have an html file and a python script, such that whenever the user clicks on an image on the website it redirects to the html page and runs the python script.

I am really lost in the python script that handles urls, module definitions, views, ..etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Apart from the image part, which is trivial, this is all covered in detail in the tutorial. You should read that.

Answer (score 5):

in your template:

```
<a href="/myapp/mylink">
    <img src="..."/>
</a>
```

in your urls.py, add a new url:

```
url(r'^mylink/$', views.mylinkview, name='mylink'),
```

add a new view:

```
def mylinkview(request):

    # ... your python code/script
    return HttpResponseRedirect('## your redirect template url ##')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is views.mylinkview, is "views" predefined?

Comment: Actually it is, when you create an app `django-admin startapp`, it will create a file named `views.py`

Comment: @Gocht I get the following error name 'views' is not defined. The project is  already implemented and deployed; so it works. I just want to add this simple feature that I know how to implement it in python but I always get module undefined, and I want to correctly point to that module.

Comment: Instead of `views` use the name of the file where your view lives.

Comment: I have the website folder that has a folder 'general' inside it and this is where my python script resides. When I use "general", I get an undefined module error "general". I need to define this view somewhere. Sorry I feel really stupid

Comment: Is this a Django project? Can you show your folders tree?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79169/discussion-between-gocht-and-poka-yoke).